# cause for stack smashing detected error in C

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors

here is the code:
used to calculate the other two sides of a right angled triangle when one of the cathetus( sides adjacent to the right angle) is given.

(i am a beginner in C)

```
int* pythagoreanTriple(int a, int *result_size){
// Complete this function

result_size[0]=a;
int sqa=a*a;
if(sqa%2)
    {result_size[1]=(sqa-1)/2;
    result_size[2]=result_size[1]++;
    }
else{
    int m=a/2;
    result_size[2]=m*m+1;
    result_size[1]=m*m-1;
}
return result_size;
}

int main() {
int a; 
scanf("%d", &a);
int result_size;

int* triple = pythagoreanTriple(a, &result_size);
for(int triple_i = 0; triple_i < 3; triple_i++) {
    if(triple_i) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("%d", triple[triple_i]);
}
puts("");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Value passed as `result_size` is not an array but used as. As the passed value is the adress of a stack allocated variable, then stack is smashed.

Answer (score 2):

In the `main` function the variable `result_size` is a single `int`. You pass a pointer to that variable to the `pythagoreanTriple` function where you treat it as an array of three elements. The pointer *could* be treated as an array, but only of a *single element*, which represents the variable in the `main` function.

If it should be an array of tree elements, then define it as such.